# Can't setup routing in .NET core Web-Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I try to make a universal method that will do some stuff. But I get a 404 with any route, even if I hardcode `{controller}` like `api/MyAwesomeController/img/{id}`. I know I did something wrong, please help me out.

P.S. I've read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and tried. But here I am

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
    routes.MapRoute("media", "api/{controller}/img/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Media", action = "Get" });
});
```

Comment: it's better to do attribute routing for web api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#routing-and-url-paths-1

Comment: it's sure is, but UNIVERSAL is what Im seeking

Comment: @Dummy please post your controller

Comment: @Alexan Allright, I get it, I'll try attrs in an hour, it's dinner time)  Will post results after

Answer (score 2):

Allright. `[Route("{tableName}/img/{id}]` **Attribute** to my universal method solved my problem. Thanx 2 @Alexan for pointing me that I already knew the answer and full stomach for good mood.

Answer (score 0):

You should be mapping in your controller like this

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
 [ApiController]
```

Your middleware should be use as template for routing and to add some custom route

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
 {
   routes.MapRoute(
      name: "default",
      template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
 });
```